# Does inserting the network scanning holotape into the institute terminal make the institute hostile later on?

Tags: fallout-4

I recently entered the Institute for the first time. I asked Sturges to examine the schematics and help me build the teleporter. Before I left though, Sturges told me to insert a holotape into an Institute terminal. The first thing I did when I entered the Institute was I inserted the holotape into the terminal.

*(Main quest line spoilers below)*

> I then met the Institute director, the main character's son, Shaun. He
>  seemed non-hostile even though I met him after inserting the holotape.

I am trying to ally with the Institute. My question is was inserting the network scanning holotape a mistake? Would this ultimately prevent me from getting the "Institute" ending?

Comment: Added an edit to contain a major spoiler for the main game. Don't want to ruin anyone's fun!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The holotape does not affect the Institute quest line. I don't think it is even brought up at any point by Father.

Comment: Can confirm, I inserted the holotape for Sturges and also completed the main quest with the Institute, it seems they never found out. Which is weird, considering they're the Institute...